# Typecasting to void pointer & back

Tags: c, multithreading, casting

I have a function:

```
void *findPos(void *param)
{
   int origPos=(int)param;
   ...
}
```

Which I am calling as a thread runner:

```
pthread_create( &threadIdArray[i], NULL, findPos, (void *)i );
```

Now, this way, I get the value of origPos as the typecasted void pointer param, ie. i. This feels like a dirty hack to get around the limitation of being allowed to pass only void pointers to a thread runner function.

Can this be done in a cleaner way?

**Edit:**

Please note that I run the `pthread_create()` function in a `i` for loop, hence passing a pointer to i may not be a safe choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hack that you shouldn't do if you want to have portable code. First the conversion back from `void*` is not necessarily well defined, as somebody else stated already.

But regardless of that, this is a dirty hack that goes against all possible intentions of the `pthread_create` API. Simply use something like this:

```
size_t * threadId = calloc(n, sizeof(size_t));
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
   threadId[i] = i;
   ptread_create(...., &threadId[i]);
}
```

And you don't have the congestion on `i` that you would have if you pass the same argument to all the threads.

Comment: Great answer, but Christoph beat you to it.

Comment: @crypto: neve mind ;-) but are you sure he did his third edit before I gave my answer ?-) and also I don't like the idea in his to have a `static` array, this supposes that the number of threads is statically known in advance.

Comment: I must've overlooked the "static vs. dynamic no. of threads" part.

Answer (score 3):

Sure: just supply a pointer to the `int`, as was the intention of the API designer:

```
void *findPos(void *param)
{
   int origPos=*(int *)param;
   ...
}

pthread_create( &threadIdArray[i], NULL, findPos, &i );
```

Casting between `int` and`void *` is unsafe because the conversion is not necessarily invertible.

You must also ensure that `i` is still valid when the thread starts executing (if `i` has automatic storage duration, this would eg be the case if the calling function also calls `pthread_join()`).

In your case (`i` being a loop variable), you should duplicating the variable's value in a safe location, eg on the heap via `malloc()` or by pushing it on a stack with appropriate liefetime:

```
static int args[THREAD_COUNT];

for(int i = 0; i < THREAD_COUNT; ++i)
{
    args[i] = i;
    pthread_create(&threadIdArray[i], NULL, findPos, args + i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could pass a pointer to the value, or wrap the value in a struct and pass a pointer to that. The latter isn't cleaner per se, but more expandable if you ever need more than one int worth of parameters to your thread.

**UPDATE:**
I used to suggest use of use `intptr_t` from [`<stdint.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) to express that you intend to cast this integer to/from `void *`, but reading the documentation a bit more closely (thanks, Christoph) gives:

> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to a pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: intptr_t

This would seem to indicate, just as Christoph said, that you're not safe if you go this route, so don't

Comment: keep in mind that the standard only makes guarantees about the conversion `void *` -> `intptr_t` -> `void *`; `intptr_t` -> `void *` -> `intptr_t` is allowed to change the value (as far as I know)

Answer (score 2):

You should be sure that on your system the value of your parameter has enough room inside a void-pointer (see data type `intptr_t`). Passing a `double` value could be problematic with your "direct" method.

I'm often using a parameter structur to pass values to thread (or other) functions.

```
struct Param {
   double foo;
   int bar;
};  

Param param;
param.foo = 1.0;
param.bar = 1;

pthread_create( &threadIdArray[i], NULL, findPos, &param );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's a dirty hack really. Wikipedia in its [pthreads example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads#Example) does the same.

Comment: no, it doesn't: they convert `int *` -> `void *` (which is safe and the explicit cast actually unnecessary), not `int` -> `void *`